Seifert surfaces of fibered knots
Given a fibered knot $K\subseteq S^3$, does every genus-minimizing Seifert surface appear as the fiber of a bundle $S^3\setminus K\to S^1$?

I think your question is answered here: https://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~kyodo/kokyuroku/contents/pdf/2263-04.pdf   see Sec. 4.

The answer is "yes".  See Corollary 2 on page 119 of Thurston's article A norm for the homology of 3-manifolds.
In fact, fibered knots fibre in exactly one way.  And all minimal genus Seifert surfaces (for a fixed fibered knot) are isotopic.

Since Thurston's paper is not immediately and obviously available online (?), I googled around and found A survey of the Thurston norm.  See Example 2.4 therein.
